# How to make a character jump over an obstacle in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates

I am trying to make a character be able to jump over an obstacle. While the character is in the obstacle (between the obstacle's two points and below the top of the obstacle), I want the program to exit. However, even though the character jumped over the obstacle, pygame.quit() is executed. How can I solve it?

Here is my code which has a problem.

```
if ((playerdino.x+55 > crator1loc) and (playerdino.x>crator1loc+40)):
    if playerdino.y+70<floorSurface-55:
        print('over the block')
    else:
        pygame.quit()
else:
    pass
```

Whole code in here:
https://github.com/Hal1903/RunningDino.git

Comment: Could you also push the images to Github?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh - I uploaded a video. I hope it helps you to figure out my problem, thank you.

Comment: I mean the images that your `rd.py` needs, such as *Run (2).png* etc.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh - Oh my bad, I uploaded them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logical for checking if the character is in the obstacle is wrong:

```py
if ((playerdino.x+55 > crator1loc) and (playerdino.x>crator1loc+40)):
```

is equal with

```py
if ((playerdino.x > crator1loc-55) and (playerdino.x>crator1loc+40)):
```

So `playerdino.x` is always greater than `crator1loc-55`.

You might change it to

```py
if ((playerdino.x > crator1loc-55) and (playerdino.x<crator1loc+40)):
```

Besides in your code you call `dino.updatedino(speed, win)` like `dino.updatedino(playerdino, -6, win)`. It should be `playerdino.updatedino(-6, win)`.

Comment: I really appreciate your quick, accurate, and kind help. Thank you very much!